# Building a loop for a function with an integer in it

Tags: excel, vba

I want the following the restult:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
Sub data()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As String

Dim x As Workbook
Set x = ThisWorkbook

For i = 3 To 14000 Step 1
j = i + 1
k = "$B$3:$B$100"
x.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) = "=TR($B$i:$B$j,""TR.FundTER"",""RH=date"",Ci)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I assume it's due to the quotation marks but as I did never have such a problem I am stuck and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What is `TR` I do not know that function?

Comment: It is for the Thomson Reuters Eikon plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the vba from the string and concatenate with `&`

```
Sub data()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As String

    Dim x As Workbook
    Set x = ThisWorkbook

    For i = 3 To 14000 Step 1
        j = i + 1
        k = "$B$3:$B$100"
        x.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=TR($B$" & i & ":$B$" & j & ",""TR.FundTER"",""RH=date"",C" & i & ")"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Unbelievable! I should've known... but thank you very, very much. You just saved me an unbelievable amount of time.